# Regular crashes of WindowServer on iMac27 without external monitor

Tags: macos, imac, crash

We have multiple iMacs27 in our office that have the same issue.

While working with Vectorworks (our cad-software) the system freezes and then returns to login, with all windows closed.

This issue is happening sometimes multiple times an hour, sometimes a couple times a week.

I attached part of the full report from one of the crashes below.

---

### Translated Report (Full Report Below)

```
Process:               WindowServer [-1]
Path:                  ???
Identifier:            WindowServer
Version:               ???
Code Type:             00000000 (Native)
Parent Process:        ??? [Unknown]
User ID:               

Date/Time:             2023-01-31 11:16:45.1461 +0100
OS Version:            macOS 12.6.1 (21G217)
Report Version:        12
Anonymous UUID:        60387729-B704-0560-ACA6-47AE286F7438



System Integrity Protection: 

Notes:
resampled 598 of 1793 threads with truncated backtraces from 0 pids: 
resampled 0 of 663 images missing from 331 pids: 1,99,102,103,109,114,117,125,130,133,138,139,140,144,145,148,149,152,153,154,157,158,160,161,163,166,205,207,210,215,227,235,242,244,250,254,257,265,266,267,268,269,272,274,275,276,278,279,280,281,282,283,284,286,288,289,290,291,292,293,294,295,296,305,306,307,308,310,311,312,313,318,319,321,322,324,325,326,328,329,331,332,333,334,335,340,341,342,343,344,345,346,347,348,349,350,351,353,363,364,365,366,370,375,376,377,378,379,381,382,383,387,391,394,396,397,398,399,401,405,407,408,409,418,421,422,423,425,426,428,429,430,432,433,434,435,436,439,441,443,444,445,447,448,450,451,454,455,456,461,462,464,466,469,471,473,475,476,479,480,481,482,483,484,486,487,489,490,496,497,498,499,501,502,503,504,505,507,508,509,511,514,515,516,517,518,519,526,527,529,531,532,533,535,537,538,539,540,541,543,544,547,549,552,579,596,597,607,609,611,615,621,624,625,627,629,630,631,632,633,634,636,639,647,648,654,673,675,679,680,682,683,684,686,688,691,692,694,695,696,698,699,700,701,702,703,704,705,706,707,708,709,710,713,714,718,720,731,732,733,815,816,817,818,821,823,824,827,829,830,846,848,857,858,859,860,861,870,871,873,874,876,878,879,884,885,898,914,917,922,923,928,930,934,935,940,941,947,953,954,955,967,974,978,979,980,987,994,995,1000,1002,1005,1026,1090,1092,1109,1117,1130,1174,1190,1283,1456,1461,1462,1463,1508,1509,1510,1511,1512,1528
55 unindexed user-stack frames from 1 pids: 1456
This is a watchdog-triggered termination event, and not expected to be well-represented in the legacy crash format

Crashed Thread:        Unknown

Exception Type:        

Termination Reason:    Namespace WATCHDOG, Code 1 monitoring timed out for service
(1 monitored services unresponsive): checkin with service: WindowServer returned not alive with context:
is_alive_func returned unhealthy : Display 69929656 not ready: DisplayID: 0x42b0ab8
Surface Use Counts: 1(1) 2(1) 6(3)
FB RegID: 4294968442, On Glass SurfaceIDs: 1 2 6, Transactions: [ Active: SurfaceID: 1 ] [ GPU Busy: SurfaceID: 2 ] [ GPU Busy: Surfa
40 seconds since last successful checkin, 674 total successsful checkins si

Error Formulating Crash Report:
resampled 598 of 1793 threads with truncated backtraces from 0 pids: 
resampled 0 of 663 images missing from 331 pids: 1,99,102,103,109,114,117,125,130,133,138,139,140,144,145,148,149,152,153,154,157,158,160,161,163,166,205,207,210,215,227,235,242,244,250,254,257,265,266,267,268,269,272,274,275,276,278,279,280,281,282,283,284,286,288,289,290,291,292,293,294,295,296,305,306,307,308,310,311,312,313,318,319,321,322,324,325,326,328,329,331,332,333,334,335,340,341,342,343,344,345,346,347,348,349,350,351,353,363,364,365,366,370,375,376,377,378,379,381,382,383,387,391,394,396,397,398,399,401,405,407,408,409,418,421,422,423,425,426,428,429,430,432,433,434,435,436,439,441,443,444,445,447,448,450,451,454,455,456,461,462,464,466,469,471,473,475,476,479,480,481,482,483,484,486,487,489,490,496,497,498,499,501,502,503,504,505,507,508,509,511,514,515,516,517,518,519,526,527,529,531,532,533,535,537,538,539,540,541,543,544,547,549,552,579,596,597,607,609,611,615,621,624,625,627,629,630,631,632,633,634,636,639,647,648,654,673,675,679,680,682,683,684,686,688,691,692,694,695,696,698,699,700,701,702,703,704,705,706,707,708,709,710,713,714,718,720,731,732,733,815,816,817,818,821,823,824,827,829,830,846,848,857,858,859,860,861,870,871,873,874,876,878,879,884,885,898,914,917,922,923,928,930,934,935,940,941,947,953,954,955,967,974,978,979,980,987,994,995,1000,1002,1005,1026,1090,1092,1109,1117,1130,1174,1190,1283,1456,1461,1462,1463,1508,1509,1510,1511,1512,1528
55 unindexed user-stack frames from 1 pids: 1456
This is a watchdog-triggered termination event, and not expected to be well-represented in the legacy crash format

Backtrace not available

No thread state (register information) available

Binary Images:
Binary images description not available
```

---

### Full Report

```
{"bundleID":"WindowServer","timestamp":"2023-01-31 11:16:45.00 +0100","os_version":"macOS 12.6.1 (21G217)","incident_id":"B8F41506-1AB2-4A44-B2DC-808839F4C26F","share_with_app_devs":0,"bug_type":"309","app_name":"WindowServer","name":"WindowServer"}
{
  "deployVersion" : 210,
  "variant" : "stackshot",
  "incident" : "B8F41506-1AB2-4A44-B2DC-808839F4C26F",
  "crashReporterKey" : "60387729-B704-0560-ACA6-47AE286F7438",
  "modelCode" : "iMac19,1",
  "cpuType" : "00000000",
  "osVersion" : {
    "train" : "macOS 12.6.1",
    "build" : "21G217",
    "releaseType" : "User"
  },
  "variantVersion" : 2,
  "captureTime" : "2023-01-31 11:16:45.1461 +0100",
  "pid" : -1,
  "procName" : "WindowServer",
  "bundleInfo" : {"CFBundleIdentifier":"WindowServer"},
  "termination" : {"flags":0,"indicator":"monitoring timed out for service","code":1,"namespace":"WATCHDOG","details":["(1 monitored services unresponsive): checkin with service: WindowServer returned not alive with context:","is_alive_func returned unhealthy : Display 69929656 not ready: DisplayID: 0x42b0ab8","Surface Use Counts: 1(1) 2(1) 6(3)","FB RegID: 4294968442, On Glass SurfaceIDs: 1 2 6, Transactions: [ Active: SurfaceID: 1 ] [ GPU Busy: SurfaceID: 2 ] [ GPU Busy: Surfa","40 seconds since last successful checkin, 674 total successsful checkins si"]},
  "stackshot" : {
    "processByPid" : {
      "0" : {"timesThrottled":491,"turnstileInfo":["thread 109: blocked on 1773, hops: 1, priority:
```

Comment: Have you contacted the developer of Vectorworks to see if they are aware of other customers with the same problem? I added the Monterey tag. Was there a recent Vectorworks or macOS update applied to these Macs? Do you have the resources to upgrade one of these iMacs to Ventura to see if that 'fixes' the problem, or is Vectorworks not supported (yet)?